# Set focus on popup window when tab is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser, focus

I have a page where a file will be uploaded and I am showing upload progress in a separate window as given in attachment.

My concern here is whenever user navigates to other tabs on same browser or to other applications and then click the upload page, the upload progress window should get focused as per attached graphic.

I tried windows.onfocus but this fails when user navigates to different tab on same browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what is the code you have written to display the popup?
you should use

```
window.showModalDialog('yourpage.ext', null, "dialogHeight:100px,dialogWidth:100px,resizable:no,center:yes" );
```